# What is a good way to represent (programatically) graphs/networks?

Tags: java

SO I have made this program dealing with cities and the roads linking them, and I am wondering if anyone could point me towards a way to represent this "network" graphically (in 3 or 2Ds).

Could be either a specific programming friendly file format (which I could easily generate an instance of programatically), or a specific language's api or library for such representation.

My current work is in Java, but if there's a solution in an other language it's not a problem.

Comment: C# has diagramming libraries like [Nevron](http://nevron.com/) that you could use for this, though it's pricey and using it programmatically is a bit painful. There are probably some free libraries, too, but nothing very good last time I looked (which was about a year ago).

Answer (score 3):

Graphviz. www.graphviz.org   It's free, open source and provides all the relevent theoretical background (mathematical underpinnings for sort order).

Answer (score 1):

There are many graph formats available. For example, [graph6](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/formats.html).

Also, there are many softwares and algorithms available for drawing graphs. [Graph drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing) is one of the currently active research areas.

GraphViz, NetworkX(Python) are the ones I have tried myself and are very good.